# Unable to determine the error after attempting to knit in Rstudio

Tags: knitr

[image]

After importing the template given for my assignment and uploading the necessary data, I was required to knit but after attempting to knit I received that error:

```
processing file: Project-Template.rmd
|.....                                              |  10% (unnamed-chunk-1) Quitting from lines 61-95 (Project-Template.rmd)
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:4:1: unexpected '['
3:
4: [
^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse

Execution halted
```

I tried removing the '[' but it still gives an error and won't allow me to successfully knit.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a closing chunk delimiter after the part that reads the CSV file. So add three backticks (```) in between the LoanDefaults line and the [ 2. line.

````
```{r}
# Import the original file
LoanDefaults <- read.csv("LoanDefaults.csv")
``` # add three backticks here

[ 2. Before beginning the study calculate the mean and standard deviation of the original dataset.] {style="color:blue;"}
````

Unrelated but there's a space in `.] {style="color:blue;"}` that needs removing for the style to actually be applied. There's no space for the `[ 3.` line and that works correctly.

Edit:

To OP's follow-up error in the comments, there needs to be a third backtick on line 70 in the original screenshot.

````
```{r}
kable(round(describe(LoanDefaults[,2]), 3)) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), full_width = F)
``` # there's only two backticks here in the original screenshot
````

Generally speaking, you need to have three backticks at the start of a chunk of code and three at the end. Because there's no closing backticks, it's trying to run pieces of text as if it's code.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work but a new error came up;

processing file: Project-Template.rmd
  |.........                                          |  18% (unnamed-chunk-2) Quitting from lines 68-95 (Project-Template.rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse
                                                                                                             
Execution halted

Comment: It looks like it's the same error but on line 70 in your original screenshot - there's only two backticks when there needs to be three. I've edited my answer to include this.